# How do I resolve a type 13 mismatch error when exporting data from Access to Excel?

Tags: type-mismatch

I'm trying to run this code to export data from a number of Access queries into multiple worksheets on a single Excel file, but I'm getting a run-time error 13: type mismatch. Any thoughts on how to resolve the issue?

Here's my code:

```
Sub ExportNSS()

 Dim strFilePath As String
    strFilePath = "H:\FINANCE\SCHFIN\Planning\"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSdaypctquery", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSdaypctbudgetquery", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_admn", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_1435", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_2000s", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_attendancehealth", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_food", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_bene", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_bene", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_athl", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_maint", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_bene", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_insu", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_reti", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_rent", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_actexp_rans", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSactexp_tuit", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSactexp_charteraid", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSS_carryforward", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx"", True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_budgetedrev", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSmuniPYSch19_all", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSmuni_actexp_tuit", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSschcomm_budget", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportacSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NSSmuni_budget", strFilePath + "NSSQueries.xlsx", True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Figure out which column in the spreadsheet has values that do not match the type of data in your table. As we have no information about the spreadsheet contents, data types in your table, or even the specific line that is causing the issue, it's impossible for us to do much to help. You have the ability to see what type of data each column in your table holds, and the contents of the spreadsheet columns, which means you're the only one that can see where the problem is located.